# Is it possible to subclass CAAnimation?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I just want to animate a layer's `position` property from point A to point B through an arc with center point C and radius R. So simple and yet I feel like I am trying to bend Core Animation in half to do this.

It seems like the ideal way would be to simply create a custom `CAPropertyAnimation` subclass, something like:

```
let anim = MyArcPropertyAnimation(keyPath: "position", center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat)
anim.fromValue = fromPoint
anim.toValue = toPoint
myLayer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "positionArcAnimation")
```

But I can't find any info on subclassing `CAAnimation` or any of it's derivatives. The same seems to go for [`CAValueFunction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAValueFunction_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)CAValueFunction) which otherwise seems promising as well.

Note: I got it running using [POP](https://github.com/facebook/pop) easily enough but found that, [as warned by a facebook engineer](https://medium.com/@beefon/should-you-use-pop-b986b10d4079#.5ag73ltzt), the performance was too slow for my usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems implied from the documentation that `CAAnimation` is not designed for subclassing. Also, most animations are performed in the window server (called `backboardd`) and you're definitely not going to be able to get `backboardd` to execute your code.

Anyway, it sounds like you can get the effect you want using a `CAKeyframeAnimation`. Set the `path` property of the `CAKeyframeAnimation` to the arc you want the layer to follow. Playground example:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400))
view.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
let mover = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10))
mover.backgroundColor = .redColor()
view.addSubview(mover)
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view

let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointMake(200, 200), radius: 160, startAngle: 1, endAngle: 5, clockwise: true)
animation.path = path.CGPath
animation.duration = 2
animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced
mover.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")
mover.center = path.currentPoint
```

Result:

[image: playground demo]